# Creating Movie using im.convert in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a movie out of jpg/png images in R. I have basically stored snapshots of a sankey diagram from googleVis package and trying to convert it into a movie.. the code that i use is:  (package `animation`)

```
im.convert("image*.jpg",output="anim.gif")
```

I used 10 images image1:image10. However the animation is stuck at the first image itself.

what is wrong?

Comment: Two possibilities: 1)make sure there aren't any "image*.jpg" files that you *don't* want included, 2) verify that whatever tool you're using to view the animated gif works correctly.  Also: try `im.convert('image1.jpg',output='oneimg.gif')` to make sure the output file size of `anim.gif` matches a 10-image file.

Comment: Another option:   `caTools::write.gif` can create animated gifs, although you'll have to load all your jpeg files and merge into an array.